# Filtering out the dead yeast cells and other trub during transfer from primary to secondary fermentation

Tags: secondary-fermentation, trub

Typically, when I transfer my wort from the pot to the bucket/carboy for primary fermentation, I like to use a very fine knit mesh reusable grain bag to catch all the hops, and other trub that has collected before I pitch my yeast and set aside for fermentation.  This time around, I have a sour cherry ale, and I ended up leaving the cherries in for the primary fermentation.  I have a ridiculous amount of trub now from all the cherries, and I'm wondering since I now pitched my yeast if it would be a good idea to filter it through the grain bag again?  I fear that by doing so I may trap the yeast in the trub, therefor am a little hesitant to do so before I hear someone speaking from experience saying it's ok to do.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't trap any yeast in the turbo at a rate that's noticeable.  The yeast are too small for that.  I would however worry about oxygenating the beer if fermentation is already done in primary.
A better practice would be to just let it ferment out and then put the whole fermentor in a cold fridge or a water bath with bottles of ice water for a couple days.  That will help flocculate out all the yeast and get the trub and cherries to settle.  The rack via siphon slowly to your bottling bucket and start bottling.

Comment: In my experience with cherries, most stayed afloat after cooling.  I would also have a big slotted spoon at the ready.

Comment: +1 - The key word here is oxygenating. Avoid it like the plague!